# How to sync socket messages in Python

Tags: python, sockets

so I have this server script I wrote which is supposed to receive a username and then continue to some other code. But I'm getting this error:

"OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

My theory is that the server and the client are not synced up so the server thinks it isn't receiving a message. How can I improve my code so the server actually gets the message? (I've tried a try block)

My code:

```
import socket

port = int(input("Server port: "))

try:
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.bind(("localhost",port))
    socket.listen(1)
except Exception:
    print("error while starting server")
    input()
    exit()

def receive(con,buffer):
    return str(con.recv(buffer).decode())

while True:
    con,ip = socket.accept()
    print(str(ip) + " Connected!")

    username = receive(socket,1024) # <-- error

    #other code
```

socket.close()

Client code:

```
import socket

ip = input("Server IP: ")
port = int(input("Server port: "))

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    socket.connect((ip,port))
except Exception:
    print("Error while connectine to the server!")
    input()
    exit()

def send(s,msg):
    s.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))

username = input("Username: ")

send(socket,username)

# other code

socket.close()
```

Comment: A server receives data via the *client socket* returned by `.accept()`, NOT the original *server socket*.

Comment: I noticed that. I changed it and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a variable name similar to any library name. In your case, you have used the variable `socket` to store server socket object. Hence, your code was ambiguos because you have used a library with the same name.

Below is the working code.

```
import socket

port = int(input("Server port: "))

try:
    SERVER = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    SERVER.bind(("localhost",port))
    SERVER.listen(1)
except Exception:
    print("error while starting server")
    input()
    exit()

def receive(con,buffer):
    return str(con.recv(buffer).decode())

while True:
    con,ip = SERVER.accept()
    print(str(ip) + " Connected!")

    username = receive(con,1024) # <-- error

    #other code
socket.close()
```

Comment: It works now! When I looked at your code more closely, I noticed that I used the "Server" socket object to receive instead of "con"